# how to alter table to add new column date with default value of current date?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I got confused about the alter.

I have an existing table, `register` and I want to add a `this_date` column with default value of current date. is it possible by alter? well it has already have data.

Comment: Yes it's possible to add a column with Alter Table.  What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 5):

It should be okay.

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ADD COLUMN this_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

As long as the new column is nullable and/or has a default value, there shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE "TableName" ADD "New_Column_Name" TIMESTAMP DEFAULT now();
```

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't possible for me on MySQL 5.7. It gives me an error every time.
I can do it with a `DATETIME` field and `NOW()`  as default, but not with `CURRENT_DATE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also choose where to put the column, use the keyword after:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD `MyColumn` DATETIME AFTER `LastColumn`
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 5.7, I didn't find a way to use CURRENT_DATE or its synonyms as default.

If your application will always provide values in INSERT statements and you only need a way to add a non-null column to existing data and then set values for existing row, you can work around this by providing a fixed default for the non-null date column

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN MyColumn DATE DEFAULT '2020-01-01'
```

and then update it to CURRENT_DATE

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = CURRENT_DATE
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The idea of the default value is to be applied when the row is created; **when** is of course definitively relevant for `CURRENT_DATE`! Your UPDATE solution would be OK if it is applied e.g. in a trigger applied at row creation time. So if you can improve it in that way, it could become much more useful.

Comment: AntoineL, you are of course right. I made assumptions that work for me, but not elsewhere. I'll update my answer...